# 2 proportion Z/T test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, proportion, z-test

I want to find out if 2 proportions are different or not.

For one, sample size is <30.

For the other, it's much >30.

Can I use the Z test since one size is large? Or do i have to use the t test? Or can I not compare since the numbers are very different?
I'd be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can learn from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212937/how-to-test-if-a-sample-proportion-matches-a-population-proportion-should-i-use)

> T-values are used for inference with means because the sample standard deviation has to be used as an estimate for a population standard deviation, rather than using the population standard deviation directly (this is generally unknown).
>
> Proportions are a little different in that the standard deviation of the hypothetical curve with mean $ p $ can be calculated by $ \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}} $. [...]

So for proportion, the standard deviation is not unknown, which means that you should use the $Z$-test.

However, more likely [you should rather use](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576215/two-sample-independent-test-for-proportions-z-test-or-t-test) the [Pearson's $\chi^2$ test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test) (implemented in [`prop.test` in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/prop.test)) or the [exact binomial test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135691/why-not-always-use-a-binomial-exact-test-to-compare-two-proportions-instead-of-c) (`binom.test` in R).